# Chromedriver not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use chromedriver in my project. Here is code -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=" + strings[0] + "&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off");
String content  = driver.getPageSource();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements link = doc.getElementsByClass("_1Nyybr _30XEf0");
```

In strings[0] I am using the link. But the problem here is the path I have given. When I am testing selenium on IntelliJ, the path is working perfectly. But here it is not working. This is the error I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /C:\Users\test\chromedriver.exe
```

Why is it showing "/" at the start? Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to use Selenium in an *Android* app?

Comment: @Martheen No. I just want to test something using my app. I want to press a button and selenium starts on my local machine.

Comment: By "app", do you mean an app running on your PC (as in, not an Android app)? Then why do you use Android Studio?

Comment: No by app I actually mean running on my phone. Okay so basically I am just testing web scraping using different methods using my mobile application. Can't I do that?

Comment: Technically you can have Appium, but it's not ideal for web scraping on Android since the device needs to be connected to your PC (it's more geared towards making sure your website works when accessed through mobile browsers on real hardware). You can't run Selenium directly on Android (the error message should be obvious, your Android device don't have a C drive). The correct method for webscraping on Android is pointing Jsoup to your Webview control